# Rendering complex HTML in CKEditor5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am planning to use collaborative review and track changes feature of CKEditor5. I did create a sample app with CKEditor cloud service. I find that when I provide the HTML generated using my service, it removes all styling and render as plain HTML.

I went through different issues and questions, found that I need to write the plugin. Looks like I need to start with this issue:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1314, In this issue, the reporter gave up on writing plugin and fall back to CKEditor4.

I want to render this complex [HTML](https://github.com/vikram-shityalkar/sample-html-docs/blob/master/input-plain.html)

Can anyone guide me, can CKEditor5 with cloud service will support the complex HTML? Will collaboration and track changes feature work?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation; version 5 appears to less capable — or a least less adaptable — than version 4, which I'm considering switching to.

Comment: @WayneSmallman, I was planning to use real-time collaboration service from CKEditor and which is only supported by CKEditor 5. Otherwise, CKEditor 4 is a good editor so far I saw.

Comment: I got a chance to connect with the technical team from CKEditor. The team evaluated the HTML. The HTML is little complex and has block level linking. Looks like it is difficult to implement and will take a long time.

I am not planning to use the CKEditor5 for now.